# Using Amazon RDS with android application

Tags: android, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

**Background**
I have a EC2 instance with a RDS instance(MYSQL) associated with it.
I want to use a android app to execute queries on that MYSQL instance.The Android sdk of amazon does not support RDS.
**Problem**
How do I connect my android app with RDS instance?Is it possible to use RDS(MYSQL) with an android application without sdk support?

Answer (score 9):

RDS is not a database engine. It's a service that manages the infrastructure for you that's required to maintain a highly available and fault tolerant database. It supports a number of different engines such as MySQL as you mentioned. Please read the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html) for more information.

You need to connect to your RDS MySQL instance the same way you would connect to any MySQL database. Using a library that supports MySQL, and using the hostname, username and password for your database.

However, it's probably not the best design to have phone clients connecting to your database remotely. The best thing to do would be to put a REST API on AWS that interfaces with your database.

Having n users connected to your database from each handset using your app is probably a bad idea. It means you need to have more power in your database, greatly hinders your scalability and makes things less secure as the database is exposed to the internet. With an API in front of it, you can build a much more fault tolerant, scalable and solution.

The "cloud way" to build mobile apps is to (within reason) build your application logic on the cloud and simply have your client code connect to your API. This way you can spread to more platforms (eg. IOS, Web) much more easily as you won't have to manage separate application level code for each platform. You'll just need to manage code that integrates with your already existing API.

Take a look at this [whitepaper](http://media.amazonwebservices.com/AWS_Web_Hosting_Best_Practices.pdf). Ignore the web server tier and focus on the App Server and Database tiers. This is probably the best design to go by.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "put a REST API on AWS that interfaces with your database".(the need of it and an outline of such api)

Comment: See my edit. But the AWS documentation is where you'll find the info you need. And the whitepaper I sent you is a must read for these kinds of architectures.

Comment: would you suggest a lib? and a snippet about using it in an android app, that would be a correct answer.

Comment: @LucasRT The point is that the question misunderstood what RDS actually is. You use whatever library you want to connect to a MySQL DB regardless of whether its in RDS or on localhost.

Comment: The whitepaper link is unavailable, could you help update it?