# Connecting Android to AWS RDS

Tags: android, mysql, database, amazon-web-services, cloud

I am new to Android and i am trying to set up an app that gets data input from the user and send it to a database. When i do launch the app multiple people will be creating accounts and uploading it to the database. I already have the app connect to my WAMP phpMyAdmin but i need the data to be on the cloud so people can upload there account info and pull data from it.

I researched different online cloud services and AWS seems to be the best one, i know there is a way to connect and upload/download data to the online database but after looking at different forms,videos, and documents on the actual AWS website i cant seem to fully understand how to do it.

Can somebody link me a video or blog on how to do this? i would greatly appreciate this!

Comment: If you already have it connecting to a PHP/MySQL stack then just install that on AWS. PHP would run on an EC2 instance and you could use a MySQL RDS instance. Also, did you search for this at all, because this exact question has been asked on here countless times. I recommend reading the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706281/using-amazon-rds-with-android-application

Comment: how would i connect the EC2 and RDS database together? but thanks for the answer!

Comment: If you actually read the answer to that question I linked it answers your followup question in the first and second paragraph. I linked to that for a reason. It answers your questions.

Comment: okay ill take a better look into it, thank you