# How to scale (or cloud enable) my android application

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I followed the tutorial at  [Amazon DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html) to make my android app write the data to DynamoDB. It works great. But, after reading the thread [Using Amazon RDS with android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706281/using-amazon-rds-with-android-application)  I realize I need to have REST API between my Android Application and DynamoDB.

Where is the documentation for REST api (and gateway api); is there any working example using such api, that would help me build REST API in AWS that can accept requests coming from Android apps

Comment: DynamoDB is not RDS.  Those are two very different services.

Comment: I agree those are 2 different services. But my question is different

Comment: Your question (at least on first reading) seems to be premised on a non sequitur. "I am using DynamoDB, but accessing RDS requires a REST API."  Perhaps you are saying that you see a parallel there, not a direct relationship.

Comment: The question you linked to says "The best thing to do would be to put a REST API **on AWS** that interfaces with your database.". In other words, you are able to  choose any language to write a web server that exposes a REST API that communicates with your database, and that is why you have a hard time finding documentation, because there is no straightforward answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a classical approach, you would have a dedicated API server, that exposes calls using REST (or whatever) to the clients (Android apps in your case). This API server can be in any programming language, .Net in our case. The API server typically contains an API facade that the client can call, a service layer that is called from the API facade and contains business logic and then a Data Access Layer that actually makes the calls to DynamoDB or whatever DB System you have behind. This is reasonably clean, as you can have several API facades, e.g. for a backend system, for integration systems, etc. The actualy business logic, if any, should be in the service layer.

In terms of infrastructure, we run our API server on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, which greatly simplifies deployment. You need to be able to handle various API versions, so that an older Android app which uses different API calls will still work after you have updated the API.

Having said that, for simpler projects with very little actual business logic this may be overkill. Amazon offers the [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/getting-started/) that allows you to expose logic to clients and you will be able to access DynamoDB or whatever behind it. I suggest that you experiment with the HTTP Endpoint walkthroughs to see how it works. Once you have it running, the advantage is, that you don't need a dedicated server for your API calls, but can handle everything using the Gateway and you pay only per request, so it scales nicely.

Once you know the technical approach, it makes sense to first define the interface (the API) between your clients and the server; so you can also create stub methods and work independently between the Android and Server logic.