# How can i connect my Android app with the online mysql database?

Tags: android, mysql, amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-rds

i am developing an android application which needs to connect with an online MySQL database. I have created an amazon aws account and set up an RDS MySQL database but i don't know how to send http requests from android app to database.

I think i need to create some web services in order to send http requests but is that possible when using amazon's rds service?

Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: Read this, I think this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34706994/14759470

Comment: Also, do you really need RDS for this? Why not use Firebase Realtime database or Firestore? It's great for data and you can customize it whatever you like.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have used firestore once and it was kinda hard for me to manage and access to, but i will try it too. Also, i will need to store images as byte arrays too. Is it supported on firebase or firestore too?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Amazon RDS with android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706281/using-amazon-rds-with-android-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a security perspective, it is not advisable to connect mobile apps directly to a database.

Mobile apps should connect to your application back-end that would perform authentication and determine what data the mobile user is entitled to access. The back-end can then retrieve the appropriate information from the database and return appropriate data to the app.

This also separates your application logic from the storage layer, allowing you to change information that is sent to/from the mobile apps without having to modify the code in every copy of the mobile app. You could also swap-out the database without having to change the mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

it's probably not the best design to have clients connecting to your database remotely. The best thing to do would be to put a REST API on AWS that interacts with your database.